# geoserver restApi /workspaces/{workspace}/coveragestores/{store}/{method}.{format} issue

Tags: geoserver

i want to add a raster layer through restApi use method POST

```
http://192.168.8.134:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myWorkSpace/coveragestores/myCoverage/remote.geotiff
with body ftp://user:password@192.168.8.200/MapFile/1.tif
```

and this is error msg response from geoserver

```
Failed to create reader from null and hints Hints:
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@7b538c13                                                                                   
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@432b0798[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
System defaults:
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                       
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                 
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@2cc03cd1
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                   
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null
```

and i checked logs on server

```
[gce.geotiff] - Argument "input" should not be null.
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Argument "input" should not be null.
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.<init>(AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.java:238)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.<init>(GeoTiffReader.java:211)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:335)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:77)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1594)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1534)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:144)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy43.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePost(CoverageStoreFileController.java:98)
```

but source code at  **CoverageStoreFileController.java:98** like this:

```
GridCoverageReader reader = info.getGridCoverageReader(null, null);
```

what shuold i do, help please.

ps:
use method PUT works fine , but PUT can not handle method remote

Comment: did you set the content type correctly?

Comment: maybe this implementation in JavaScript is helpful: https://github.com/meggsimum/geoserver-node-client/blob/master/src/datastore.js#L217-L240
you could extract a working API request from there

Comment: https://github.com/meggsimum/geoserver-node-client/blob/master/src/datastore.js#L217-L240
this api use PUT method, geoserver source code shows PUT can not handle remote param